# How to manipulate with external data?

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I have a .txt file which contains a lot of triples (a, b, c) (one per row) which should be coefficients of my equation ax^2+bx+c=0.
I want to include each triple in .nb file and solve each equation.
Can anyone help me with my problem?
Thanks!

Comment: use `Import` and `Solve` function

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I link the txt file data sheet to mathematica and extract exact elements that I would like to use in solving for x?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58906/how-do-i-link-the-txt-file-data-sheet-to-mathematica-and-extract-exact-elements)

Comment: How many is "a lot of triples"? An order of magnitude estimate will do.

Comment: A .txt file contains around 30 000 triples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test text file:

```
-7.101294838,6.107184564,-7.827628057
-7.776324224,3.335127227,-8.635435055
5.653804799,9.155964227,-6.508515146
-8.873230178,2.449789254,-0.713901565
-1.616786376,5.64260341,3.23697902
-5.190324765,-8.67827251,-2.506562629
6.81920439,-3.730488378,1.677649757
-5.814306708,-4.617626918,5.667566715
1.154882842,-2.126425841,-8.933609026
-1.665101552,4.396558494,-5.940551083
6.544643025,-9.096806506,-7.002028455
6.04854105,-7.739195416,-1.276841486
3.871768557,-7.198530082,-9.46446542
-0.680785889,3.464811906,-2.929132405
-4.357425836,5.631310807,-1.711637437
2.133636139,-0.073688277,9.525442198
-5.439028936,-4.829169073,-9.476025827
-9.571569236,8.916887043,-4.537750212
5.057792327,8.94809071,7.972750284
-9.188019054,-3.027845952,2.932524861
```

Import text:

```
coeffs = Import["pathtofile.txt", "CSV"];
```

Solve:

```
NSolve[#1*x^2 + #2*x + #3 == 0, x] & @@@ coeffs
```

> {{{x -> 0.430005 - 0.957798 I}, {x -> 0.430005 + 0.957798 I}}, {{x -> 
>       0.214441 - 1.03174 I}, {x -> 
>       0.214441 + 1.03174 I}}, {{x -> -2.1539}, {x -> 0.534462}}, {{x -> 
>       0.138044 - 0.247789 I}, {x -> 
>       0.138044 + 0.247789 I}}, {{x -> -0.501581}, {x -> 3.99159}},...

Comment: Thank you! 

And if I want to print out only integer solutions (pairs with at least one integer solution) of my equation, is there any better way than to make another list, with solutions, and then going through all of them with IntegerQ command?

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve once and then replace the a, b, c variables in the general solution with each triple of values.

The import of a .txt file as a "Table" should end up with a table like (could be integers, reals, or a combination)

```
SeedRandom[8];

data = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {10, 3}];
```

Convert each triple to substitution rules:

```
substitutionRules = Thread[{a, b, c} -> #] & /@ data
```

> {{a -> -5, b -> -3, c -> -1}, {a -> 3, b -> -2, c -> 1}, {a -> -5, b
>   -> 2,    c -> -3}, {a -> 2, b -> 2, c -> 0}, {a -> 2, b -> -1, c -> 4}, {a -> 0,    b -> 3, c -> 5}, {a -> -2, b -> -2, c -> -5}, {a -> 0,
>   b -> 0,    c -> 1}, {a -> 2, b -> -2, c -> -3}, {a -> 5, b -> 5, c ->
>   1}}

One time generic solution:

```
sol =
 Piecewise[{
   {{{}}, a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0},(* all x *)
   {{}, a == 0 && b == 0},(* no x *)
   {Solve[b*x + c == 0, x], a == 0}},
  Solve[a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0, x]]
```

[image]

Substituting each triple into the generic solution:

```
sol /. substitutionRules // Column
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact format of you input file, this could work.

```
Solve[#[[1]] x^2 + #[[2]] x + #[[3]] == 0, x] & /@ 
 Import["...\\coeff.txt", "csv"]
```